# I'm finding Brutal: Paws of Fury very hard, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sega-genesis, brutal-paws-of-fury

I bought Brutal: Paws of Fury about a year ago, but put it away because it was too damn hard to beat the game (I only got to level 3 by mind-numbingly blocking all the time and inserting a punch per minute or so).

Is there any real strategy as to how I should handle the game? Is there a way to make it more humane and let me have at it from time to time, instead of just getting beat up every time?
Are there cheats to lower the chaos-whirling attacks of the opponents (just so that they are doable)?

Comment: http://www.gamefaqs.com/segacd/919440-brutal-paws-of-fury/faqs/27423

Comment: thanks for the faq on the characters, but this holds no strategy.. Have you ever seen a vid of the game? It's horrifying to play against the game itself, as it litterally beats the crap out of you. It's like a crue joke.. >_>

Comment: its literally all I could find